# reactjs axios mockAdapter return error before send request

Tags: reactjs, axios, request

This is my error:

TypeError: mockAdapter.originalAdapter is not a function

````
 try {
  const response: AxiosResponse<IValidateEmail> = await landlord.post(VALIDATE_EMAIL, { email 
                                                                 ^   
  },defaultHeaders())                                               
  return response.data
 } catch (error) {}```


he intentado desactivar las pruebas de MockAdapter pero no lo he conseguido
````

Answer (score 0):

checking the documentation of axios-mock-adapter and guiding me through the written code, I could find that I must necessarily do a unit test for that service that I am consuming, for example, my service goes to /login, so what I must do is a test unitary for that endpoint with that parameters

a quick example

`mock.onPost('/login').reply(() => { return [ 200, { code: 200, tenant: 'demo', group: 'admin', email: 'brandon@yopmail.com', access_login: 'eyJhbGciOiJ..........' } ] })`

This is just for beginners, for those of us who don't know much about mock-adapter,